# Possible to make Visual Studio 2010 tabbed interface make sense?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tabs

Is there an easy way to make the Visual Studio 2010 tabbed interface work like you would expect? Basically I want it to work like a web browser:

`CTRL + W` = Close current Tab (not select current word)

`CTRL + TAB` = Switch to tab on right of current tab (do not bring up tab selection window)

`CTRL + SHIFT + TAB` = Switch to tab on left of current tab (do not bring up tab selection window)

Is there anyway for the tabs to always open up in chronological order and stay that way. By default, Visual Studio will open them up chronologically, but then change the order based on what you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

To change/override the keyboard commands go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.  Assign your preferred key in the shortcut and by choosing the command you want.

Something like the screenshot below
[image]

For the chronological ordering I am afraid its not supported out of the box, you might need some macro or third party add-ons (not sure if there are any)